# apache and mysql start button are disabled in xampp control panel

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

When I install xampp its working fine. But once after restart/shutdown, It giving this error.

```
[Apache] Problem detected: Apache not found.
[Apache] Disbling apache buttons
[Apache] Run this program from your apache root directory.
[mysql]  Problem detected: mysql not found 
[mysql]  Diabling mysql buttons
[mysql]  Run this program from your apache root directory.
```

Xampp version: xampp-win32-1-8-3-4-VC11-installer

System configuration: windows 7 32 bit

Note: while install it shows to disable the UAC.

Here is the image:
[image: xampp start buttons disabled]

Comment: The program is unable to find the bat files to start the processes so they disable the button. Did you move the control panel? Try running 'setup_xampp.bat' in your xampp folder aswell

Comment: No i didn't move the any files. You said `program is unable to find bat files` it means some files are missing?

Comment: In your installation folder there should be apache_start.bat and apache_stop.bat, mysql_start.bat etz. I would reinstall as a administrator like CJB suggested and see if they get installed this time.

Comment: apache_start.bat , mysql_start.bat files are available inside the root xampp

Comment: when i run setup_xampp.bat . It gives an alert message **"the program can't start because php5ts.dll is missing. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"**

Comment: That means you're still missing files. Reinstall as administrator like CJB said, its the only solution I can think off right now

Comment: i tried all and tired. Reinstalling. Download a new pack and installing. It runs after installing/reinstalling and the issue raises after restarting system for 2 or 3 times.

Comment: i think its due to some system issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing as admin and disable your anti virus when installing, you can also disable UAC as well. And always run as Admin when launching by right clicking the .exe and go properties and set "Run as Administrator"

Comment: I tried all these. Did reinstalling and restarting for number of times. After each installation as administrator, Its working fine. then I'm getting this error after restart the system for 1 or two times. I guess its due to some system issue, but can't predict the exact reason. Already i have uninstalled all the unnecessary softwares.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, so yours is installed like this correct? C:\xampp    can you right click on your apache folder and compare sizing. Mine is 65.4MB in size and 68.1MB on disk

Comment: size of c:\xampp is around 700MB.

Comment: Does "windows update service" affect the installed apps??  while restart/start the system its started updating.

Comment: Is this problem solved? @Muthukumar I am facing the same problem

Comment: @chinmayahd Nope :( .. It doesn't work fa me. I gave up on this and just changed the OS..

Comment: In my case, httpd.exe somehow got deleted from xampp\apache\bin\ and xampp was showing "Problem detected: Apache not found" Error. I just copied this file from some other PC and pasted and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

Find the  `httpd.exe`  in the specified route.

```
C:\xampp\apache\bin
```

Comment: There is no `httpd.exe` there

Answer (score 1):

first check your xampp folder where apche/bin and mysql/bin is available or not.if it is not available then search it into your drive and put the xampp folder as it is.And last restart your xampp control panel and start the apache and mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me yesterday after a crash. It was saying Tomcat was not found, and the buttons were disabled. First thing I checked was if Tomcat was in the Xampp directory and could be started manually. It could, so I started looking for configuration errors. I clicked the config button at the top, then service and port settings, and then the Tomcat tab. I saw immediately that Xampp was looking for Tomcat 7, and that was the problem. I had updated to 8 a long time ago and I guess when the system crashed, Xampp reverted to the default config. I changed that to 8, and restarted Xampp. Problem solved, but the buttons were still disabled. I then discovered that in the xampp-control.ini file, under the ServiceNames section, it said Tomcat=Tomcat7. I changed that to Tomcat8 and restarted Xampp, and the buttons were working again. I would imagine it would be a similar procedure for any of the other modules not being detected. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

you placed xampp control on the desktop for a quick start this is the main reason for disabled apache and MySQL button. try to start from install xampp folder.