# XAMPP Mysql won't start

Tags: mysql, xampp

I've been using XAMPP for a couple of months and suddenly I'm getting an error in XAMPP that I haven't been able to find a solution.

```
12:07:28  [mysql]   Problem detected: MySQL Not Found!
12:07:28  [mysql]   Disabling MySQL buttons
12:07:28  [mysql]   Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!
```

This is the error I'm getting from the XAMPP control panel.

When I go to the XAMPP root directory and try to run the mysql_start.bat file it says

```
mysql\bin\mysqld is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
```

I'm not sure what to do from here to get everything working again.

Comment: This may help: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/08/mysql-how-to-find-mysqld-exe-with-command-prompt-fix-mysql-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/

Comment: Does not seem to find mysqld. I've search all of the C: drive for it to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the OS in which you are working. Most possible solution is to install the xampp application as admin and disable anti virus during the installation process. Also disable UAC if in windows. Run the application as administrator. This post is taken from a previously asked question on the same topic. You can find it here

[apache and mysql start button are disabled in xampp control panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777169/apache-and-mysql-start-button-are-disabled-in-xampp-control-panel)

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. 
But the strange thing is everything has worked before? I have a lot of files and database tables that I would have to backup if I have to reinstall?

Comment: Possibly yes.But then again the directory of your database is probably in C:\xampp\mysql\data. See if you can copy paste that in some other directory before a reinstall.